# How to populate an ArrayList from EditText and a button / Initializing an object

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

Hello how can I populate my `ArrayList` with an `EditText` and a `button`, the problem is that I don't know how from `EditText` I can initialize an object and then add It to my `ArrayList`

Thank you

[image]

//**Main activity**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        Todo eat = new Todo("Eat ");
        Todo sleep = new Todo("Sleep");

        ArrayList<Todo> todolist = new ArrayList<>();
        todolist.add(eat);
        todolist.add(sleep);

        Todoadapter adapter = new Todoadapter(this,R.layout.custom_adapter_layout,todolist);
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

// **Object**

```
public class Todo {
    private String todo;
    public Todo(String todo) {
        this.todo = todo;
    }
    public String getTodo() {
        return todo;
    }
    public void setTodo(String todo) {
        this.todo = todo;
    }
}
```

//**ArrayAdapter**

```
public class Todoadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Todo> {

private Context mcontext;
int mresource;
private List<Todo> objects = new ArrayList<>();

public Todoadapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Todo> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mresource = resource;
    this.mcontext = context;
    this.objects = objects;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    String todo = getItem(position).getTodo();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mresource, parent, false);
    final CheckBox box = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    box.setText(todo);
    box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(box.isChecked()){
                //Delay to see animation
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        objects.remove(getItem(position)); //Your object list where you have the itens
                        notifyDataSetChanged(); //If you are using a recycler view.
                    }
                },300); //adding 0.3 sec delay
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;

}

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add listener for button either in XML or via java

`activity_main`

```
<Button ...
  android:id="@+id/button"
  android:onClick="addTodo"/>
```

In `MainActivity.java`

1.) Make adapter and list instance global to class

2.) Create `addTodo` method (keep it public and add View parameter)

3.) After click, fetch data from edittext, create a Todo instance and add it to list

4.) Notify the adapter to reflect the changes

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // 1
    private ArrayList<Todo> todolist;
    private Todoadapter adapter;
    private EditText edit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        Todo eat = new Todo("Eat ");
        Todo sleep = new Todo("Sleep");

        todolist = new ArrayList<>();
        todolist.add(eat);
        todolist.add(sleep);

        adapter = new Todoadapter(this,R.layout.custom_adapter_layout,todolist);
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    // 2
    public void addTodo(View view){
        // 3
        todolist.add(new Todo(edit.getText().toString()));
        // 4
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer
I've done all the things you said, when I click on the button add, my application is closing, it says " .. keeps stopping"

Comment: @Blebhebhe can you post the error details from logcat

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.alexandre.hei, PID: 16153                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
EDIT : gonna put the error in the main post

Comment: @Blebhebhe please edit your answer and add complete details of error, so that i can see the actual reason and there was a typo with `...add(new Todod)`, hope   you rectified it

Comment: @Blebhebhe note the `edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);`  line

Comment: Ah yes ! I found the problem, my ArrayList, todoadapter and edit were never initialized . 
because
I kept these like this :  
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
ArrayList<Todo> todolist = new ArrayList<>();
same for adapter... Thank you very much !

Comment: @Blebhebhe i am glad that i could help, happy coding , though with your previous approach, your edittext and adapter will behave like local variables, only usable inside oncreate method

Comment: Oh I see ... So,   is it " strongly " recommended to always declare variable outside method ?? as you did there :  private ArrayList<Todo> todolist;
    private Todoadapter adapter;
    private EditText edit;

Comment: @Blebhebhe not really  but when you have an object (adapter, list, todo) which requires to be modified later then it's better to keep them outside methods (especially when they are heavy objects like adapter , list, button, edittext etc)

Answer (score 1):

```
      buttonsetOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            String data=edit.getText().toString();
            if(data.isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
             }
               todolist.add(new Todo(data));
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } 
        });
```

add above code in your onCreate, remember you have to validate `edit text` data before you add it to `todolist` otherwise app may crash.

Comment: Thank you, it works ! Sorry , It seems that I can't accept multiple answer :(

Comment: It's okay, No worries, it has been my pleasure helping you.